# Speed up joins on thousands of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, query-optimization

I have two tables that look something along the lines of:

```
t1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, data VARCHAR(10), fkey INT, INDEX i1(data))
t2 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, enabled TINYINT)
```

And a query to get data from `t1`. The query runs fine and takes a few ms to get data from it, although problems start appearing when I use joins. Here's an example of one of my queries:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `t1` WHERE `data`='something';
```

Which can return a few thousand rows, that might look something like:

```
1, something, 5
2, something, 5
3, something, 5
4, something, 6
5, something, 5
```

Out of these thousands of rows, there are probably only going to be one or two distinct values of `fkey`. Now, here's my query with the join:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id` FROM `t1` 
INNER JOIN `t2` 
   ON `t2`.`id`=`t1`.`fkey` 
   AND `t2`.`enabled`=1 
WHERE `t1`.`data`='something';
```

And here's the execution plan for it:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: id
          key: id
      key_len: 75
          ref: NULL
         rows: 378
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: i1
          key: i1
      key_len: 150
          ref: DB.t2.id,const
         rows: 13
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
```

This query ends up taking roughly 60 seconds, compared to the few ms of the other query. I've also tried removing the `enabled` check from the query, but it has no impact on performance. Also, querying `t2` directly by id only takes a few ms as well.

It seems to me like the database should only have a need to run the join on one or two rows and just cache the results for any rows with the same `fkey`, but that doesn't seem to be happening. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: what indexes have you created on your tables and what is the execution plan printed by the "explain" statement of your query?

Comment: The only index is the one listed above for data on t1, as well as primary keys for both ids.

Comment: This already had the indexes I'd use. You could argue for adding `enabled`, but since you're already looking up into t2 by unique indexed ID I'm skeptical it'd help much. Similarly, you might want to update `INDEX i1(data)` to `INDEX i1(data, fkey)` or `INDEX i1(data, fkey, id)`, but for the latter option you end up using every field in the table and for the former you have to go back to the original table anyway.

Comment: A query that selects only one column cannot return 3 columns

Comment: How many rows in each table?

Comment: @Strawberry It's an example of the table contents, not the query.

Comment: @RickJames t1 has a few million rows, but the query (not including the join) filters it down to a few thousand, and t2 has a few hundred.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` does not agree with the stated indexes.  Please get them in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I've finally come across a good solution for this that significantly reduces the time it takes to run these queries.

This query:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id` FROM `t1` 
INNER JOIN `t2` 
   ON `t2`.`id`=`t1`.`fkey` 
   AND `t2`.`enabled`=1 
WHERE `t1`.`data`='something';
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id` FROM `t1`
WHERE `t1`.`data`='something' 
AND `t1`.`fkey` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `t2` WHERE `t2`.`enabled`=1);
```

This will query and compare on all values from `t2`, which isn't ideal if it only needs one or two, but it's better than nothing.

If someone has a solution that does do the comparison on only a few and it isn't some MySQL hack then I'll mark it as accepted, but for now, this works pretty well.

EDIT:
As @Joel Coehoorn and @eshirvana pointed out, indexing `fkey` in `t1` is helpful, but only really has an affect on queries 8k+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more information including query execution plan , but for starter, if you don't have an index on fkey you should add one and another one for data:

```
create index indx_name on t2(enabled)
create index indx_name2 on t1(id,fkey, data)
```

Comment: I'll make an edit with the execution plan, but could you explain a bit more what the purpose of the index on fkey is for? At least from what I understand, indexes are used to lookup rows, but fkey is being used to look up another row. Also, fkey doesn't exist on t2, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: ok , index will help to avoid full scan and improve your performance . also put fkey on wrong table

Comment: enabled is a flag; I doubt its index will do much for performance

Comment: Having `id` first is probably wasteful since it is the PK.  And a PK is an index.

Comment: @RickJames no matter you mention pk in an index or not , it will be always part of index , so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: The order of the columns in any index _is_ important.

Answer (score 0):

Given the table definitions provided this already had the indexes I'd use.

You could argue for adding an index on `t2` with both `enabled` and `id`, but since you're already looking up into `t2` by unique indexed id I'm skeptical it'd help much.

Similarly, it's tempting to update `INDEX i1(data)` to `INDEX i1(data, fkey)` or `INDEX i1(data, fkey, id)`, but for the latter option you end up using every field in the table and for the former you have to go back to the original table anyway.

Where this breaks down is if the table definitions for the question are incomplete relative to the real problem. If you have more fields in these tables the indexes above do start to look appealing to me, because they save potential disk activity relative to reference the full table.

Comment: If `t1` is InnoDB, then `id` (the PK) will be tacked onto each secondary index.  (That makes the last two suggestions equivalent.)